# Custom Login form in a Rails app with third party Oauth authentication webservice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, authentication, oauth, devise

We use devise to manage user sessions, password reset requests and new registrations in a Rails app that I am maintaining.

Currently I'm replacing the present omniauth authentication flow (which is the only alternative currently present for auth in the app) with a new authentication scheme integrating an in-house developed RESTful webservice. For this, I have overriden the default devise `views` and `controllers`:

For example:

If I `PUT` to http://webservice/api/login with `{ username: "username", password: Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("password") }`, through an OAuth API consumer (it uses Oauth security), I can get a response like:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "oauth_token": "[hex string]",
    "oauth_verifier": "[hex string]",
    "session_token": "[hex string]"
  }
}
```

..provided that I actually send correct values to that route. This effectively offsets the complexities of authentication to the web service.

I have the following routes for devise:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: "sessions",
    passwords: "passwords",
    registrations: "registrations",
    omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"
  }

devise_scope :user do
    get  "sign_in",        to: "sessions#new",           as: :new_user_session
    post "sign_in",        to: "sessions#submit",        as: :submit_user_session
    get  "reset_password", to: "passwords#new",          as: :reset_password
    post "reset_password", to: "passwords#submit",       as: :submit_reset_password
    get  "register",       to: "registrations#new",      as: :new_user_registration
    post "register",       to: "registrations#submit",   as: :submit_registration
    match "sign_out",      to: "sessions#destroy",       as: :destroy_user_session, via: [:get, :post, :delete]
  end
```

So what I've done is that in `/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb` I make a form to gather user input, then `POST` those inputs to `sessions_controller.rb`, gather them in the controller and `PUT` the `params` I gathered to the external webservice. I'm currently able to do this perfectly:

```
api_token = OAuth::AccessToken.new @api_consumer, request_token.token, request_token.secret
response = api_token.put "/api/login", { username: username, password: Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password) }
```

And I can get a `response` just fine, which I parse to abstract the `session_token` out of.

My question is, how do I use this `session_token` to make the app recognize a user as logged in? How can I plug that value somewhere to let the user access sensible resources?

The app also uses warden and doorkeeper and warden to manage authentication... any ideas as to how this may affect me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

Your user model must remain `:omniauthable` for this.

I built the forms and used the routes as expected and explained above, respectively. Business as usual defining the views for devise.

In my sessions controller, I talked to the auth web service and I obtained the response, which I `cased` out to isolate different processes applying to whether the response was successful or not (if `response.success?` else...)

After that, under the if `response.success?` block I used the a session token I got from the webservice to pull up the user's session from the tables. Devise should store sessions for the users. In my app this was done using a `Credential` model, which persisted its info to a `Credentials` table, and which is linked to the `Users` table with...

```
belongs_to :user_identifier,
    foreign_key: :uid,
    primary_key: :platform_resource_id

  has_one :user,
    through:  :user_identifier,
    source:   :user
```

and also has all that yummy Kansas-style ActiveRecord ORM sauce baked in, so I did:

```
credential = Credential.find_or_create_by(token: @session_token, token_type: 'session_token')
```

Then just call the devise method `sign_in` using the `user` corresponding to the `Credential` you pulled from the database. Bear in mind this is all still from the sessions controller where you're doing all of this talking and parsing to the auth webservice:

```
sign_in credential.user, event: :authentication #sign in the user!
```

Feel free to mix and match according to your schema and field names. Your session tokens must be stored somewhere, find it brave programmers you little beautiful things you!

Notice how I'm using ActiveRecord's `find_or_create_by`, only in the block pertaining to the success case when polling the auth webservice. That webservice does `200 OK` when authentication is successful, and `4xx` when things go awry.

If anyone needs to do something like this in the future, please check that your provider offers an API like this to get stuff done, I don't think all oauth providers do. If my advice isn't enough for your needs, feel free to shoot me a message and I'll try to help. I went through hell to figure this out so I wouldn't want anyone to have a bad time again :^)

Comment: I'm trying to implement an oauth strategy with a third-party for single-sign-on. It doesn't have its own gem, so should I write everything from scratch.
My understanding is that doorkeeper allows you to do this if you have control over that other server.
I'm currently using just devise. Any tips, articles or directions would be appreciated